# Why can't I delete last element of vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

I have stl vector consisting of several elements. I need to iterate through this vector and delete elements which meets some criteria. So I wrote this code

```
for (int j = imageDataVector.size()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(imageDataVector[i] < threshold)
        imageDataVector.erase(imageDataVector.end() - j);
}
```

This code works fine for almost all cases, however if all elements of vector meets the criteria I get an error:

```
vector erase iterator outside the range
```

This error occurs if I have only one element left in the vector. What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 11):

```
if(imageDataVector[i] < threshold)
        imageDataVector.erase(imageDataVector.end()-j);
```

Should likely be:

```
if(imageDataVector[j] < threshold)
        imageDataVector.erase(imageDataVector.begin()+j);
```

EDIT: for completeness, the erase-remove way and the iterator way:

```
imageDataVector.erase(std::remove_if(imageDataVector.begin(), imageDataVector.end(), std::bind2nd(std::less<vector_data_type>(), threshold)), imageDataVector.end());

vector<type>::iterator it = imageDataVector.begin();
while (it != imageDataVector.end()) {
  if (*it < threshold)
    it = imageDataVector.erase(it);
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Comment: +1, It is important to note that the *good* way is the *erase-remove* idiom, as it is more efficient than the others (in particular, in the worst case where all elements meet the criteria, *erase-remove* is linear *O(N)*, while the other two versions have quadratic performance *O(N^2)*

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing forward and backward indexing.

I'd consider using `std::remove_if` instead. That way if you're removing multiple elements you don't shift the entire vector forwards on each erase.

It would look something like this:

```
imageDataVector.erase(std::remove_if(imageDataVector.begin(), imageDataVector.end(), std::bind2nd(std::less<data_type>(), threshold)), imageDataVector.end());
```

Alternately try the following, noting that it will result in a lot of movement if you remove multiple items from the vector.

```
for (int j=imageDataVector.size()-1 ;j>=0;j--)
{
    if(imageDataVector[i] < threshold)
        imageDataVector.erase(imageDataVector.begin()+j);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to remplace std::less<>() with some more fancy function?? Sth like comparator in c# ??

Comment: @igor You can replace it with anything that takes one parameter and returns true if the item should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to count down j to zero, and `imageDataVector.end() - 0` is not a valid iterator. In the standard C++ library containers, the end iterator points one past the last element, not at the last element.