# C++ : Convention on iterator when doing slicing, especially for accessing to the last element and eventually remove it

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, stdvector

I have the following function that is supposed to compute the sum of all elements of a vector :

```
double arraySum(vector<double> const &v) {

    double initial_sum  = 0.0;
    return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), initial_sum);
}
```

From antoher side, if I have the following list and I want to delete the last string, I do :

```
   param_chain_A = {"wm", "wde", "wb", "w0", "wa", "h", "ns", "s8", "gamma", "A_IA", "n_IA", "B_IA", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "b10", "b11"};

    if (model == "S") {
      param_chain_A.erase(param_chain_A.end()-1);
    }
```

As you can see, in the first example, I used `v.end()` for the last element of a vector and `param_chain_A.end()-1` for the last element of a list.

I just want to understand better how to identify the last element for a vector and a list with keywords `.end()`.

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225229/why-cant-i-delete-last-element-of-vector), it is said that :

> "You're trying to count down j to zero, and imageDataVector.end() - 0
>   is not a valid iterator. In the standard C++ library containers, the
>   end iterator points one past the last element, not at the last
>   element."

**So my question is simple : is there a difference between accessing to the last element (for eventually to remove it) of a vector and last element of a list ?**

If no, how to handle in both case this kind of stuff (removing the last element)

I have a third example where I want to extract a subvector of an initial vector :

```
// Slice for arrays like python syntax
vector<double> slice(vector<double> const &v, int m, int n)
{
    vector<double>::const_iterator first = v.begin() + m;
    vector<double>::const_iterator last = v.begin() + n;

    vector<double> vec(first, last);
    return vec;
}
```

In this case, I extract the vector beginning at the `m+1 element` up to including `n+1 element` of vector `v`, don't I ? Here, I don't use `.end()`.

I have to indicate that I would like to get a `std-c++11` convention (if possible).

PS: I saw that there was `.rbegin()` iterator **to access directly to the last element**, but is it a problem to use `std-c++14` instead of `std-c++11` versions, I mean, for a basic scientific code (I don't push too far away the "object" logical of C++ in my code, simply using a class with classical attributes and methods).

Comment: Aside: rather than returning `vector<double>`, you could return `first, last` as a pair of iterators (perhaps wrapped in `boost::any_range` or similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, in the first example, I used v.end() for the last element of a vector

No, you did not. You used `v.end()` to denote the *end* of the sequence. That's different from the last element.

Ranges in C++ (by convention) are [half-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology). It's just like when you use a `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` loop; the range is 0 to 10, but the loop never sees when `i` gets the value 10. `i` only assumes the values 0 through 9. 10 is used only to determine when to terminate the loop; it is not an element in the loop.

The same goes for any "end" iterator; it is a valid iterator in the sense that you can subtract from it (if the iterator allows that). But it is not a dereference-able iterator; if you try to do `*v.end()`, you get undefined behavior. It simply defines when you have reached the "end" of the sequence defined by the iterator.

Using half-open ranges allows you to specify an empty range, where the beginning and terminal conditions are both the same.

> I extract the vector beginning at the `m+1` element up to including `n+1` element of vector `v`, don't I ?

No, you don't.

Assuming standard C++ conventions of zero-based indices, the beginning of your new vector will contain the `m`th element of the old. The last element in your new vector will contain the `n-1`th element of the old, because the iterator that *terminates* the copying process is the iterator to the `n`th element (assuming there is an `n`th element; there doesn't have to be, so long as there's an `n-1`th element).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to access the last element of a vector and a list. There is member methods for that:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<char> letters {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    std::vector<int> numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    if (!letters.empty()) {
        std::cout << "The last character is: " << letters.back() << '\n';
    }  
    if (!numbers.empty()) {
        std::cout << "The last numbrer is: " << numbers.back() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use std::prev,

```
auto it = numbers.end();
if (it != numbers.begin()){
    std::cout << *prev(it) << std::endl;
}
```